# RESTapi and MQTT Broker

Tags: mqtt, web-services, rest-api

**Question:**
What I'm trying to do is to get the REST API to be able to publish to my Mosquitto MQTT Broker (which is also hosted on my Pi on Port 1883) via IFTTT Webhook.

**Context**

I've built a webapp using ASP.NET Core and it is being hosted on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ using NGINX. Likewise, I've also made a RESTFUL API using ASP.NET Core.
As for the REST API, I can either publish it to Microsoft Azure / Host it on my Pi as well, whichever is better in the solution given.

**What I've tried**

I've had a successful attempt using Home Assistant's REST API `/api/service/mqtt/publish` but to no avail when setting up my own. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in my ASP.NET Core REST API configuration. I did it just as how I would do any HttpPost thinking it would work.

Code

```asp
[Route("api/broker")]
[ApiController]
public class BrokerController : ControllerBase
{
    #region HTTPGET
    // HTTP GET: /api/broker
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Broker> Get()
    {
        List<Broker> dbList = DBUtl.GetList<Broker>("SELECT * FROM Broker");
        return dbList;
    }
}
```

Things I've attempted:

1. Butler-mqtt-master.

- Got it working and it says "Rest Server Listening on http://[::]:8081" But I've no idea what exactly does that mean. My API is available on a azure api link.

2. mqtt2rest-master

- Outdated (i think?)

Successful Workaround (but not very reliable / fully functional):

1. Node-RED

- By using a `inject node` to constantly poll a `http request node` at a fixed interval of 4 seconds together with a `function node` and finally pushing the object obtained (with mqtt payload in JSON) to the `mqtt node`, I am able to get bridge from HTTP RESTapi to MQTT Broker. But this method has lots of loopholes and isn't efficient. If possible I want mine to be working in the same as as how home assistant works.

Link: https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/en/external_api_rest.html

E.G: Sending a POST request to https:///api/services/mqtt/publish? will send my POST request to the MQTT Broker (which I have no idea how that works)

Comment: Without seeing the code you've tried we can fix it

Comment: Hi @hardillb , i've added the code. for the downvotes - would be great if you gave comments on additional details I could provide to better help the question - Thank you!

Comment: This is is a generic programming question and as such should probably be on Stack Overflow (but you are going to need to show more effort to actually implement some MQTT logic in your code before anybody will help)

Comment: Welcome aboard, Eric. I hope that you can update your question and get an answer. About the downvote - I am afraid that it happens often, and people don't bother to explain why; that's the frustrating part - I wouldn't mind a downvote if they told me what I did wrong. Please don't let it discourage you.

Comment: @hardillb sorry i was deciding the two and decided here since it involves mqtt/iot stuff. The problem i'm having is i do not know how i can implement MQTT logic into my ASP.NET RESTapi. What i've tried though is using some mqtt-rest bridge available on git but so far none seemed to work...

Comment: @Mawg thank you Mawg! Will try to keep my questions as detailed as i can!.

Comment: I honestly don't know, Eric. There are far more people on S.O than here, but we have the knowledge here. OTOH, they will obviously be a few there who know too.  I guess the answer is that S.O requires you to 1) post code 2) say what it ought to do 3) say what is going wrong. Since you can’t really do that, I guess that here is best. But the guideline of “the more detail you give, the higher quality answer you are likely to receive” applies to all SE sites. I miss Sg; wonder if my PR has lapsed :-(

Comment: @Mawg Yes, more details - i wouldn't mind providing. Do let me know if there's anything else i may add-on to improve my question! If there's no answers i might consider posting on S.O

Answer (score 1):

May be it is simpler to use MQTT Broker that supports REST API by its nature? Like [flespi broker](https://flespi.com/mqtt-broker) which contain secure and private MQTT namespace, free to use and actively used by some [home automations systems](https://flespi.com/blog?tag=diy). The REST API for messages publishing is described [here](https://flespi.io/mqtt/#/tags/!/messages/post_messages).